# Translating multiple domains to paths in a Tomcat app

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, url-routing

If I have 2 domains, and 2 subdomains:

```
examples.com
dogs.tutorials.com
cats.tutorials.com
```

And I want to serve them from one Tomcat server as a Java application from the following application entry paths:

```
localhost/app/examples/
localhost/app/tutorials/dogs/
localhost/app/tutorials/cats/
```

For example:

```
dogs.tutorials.com/search/?f=terrier
```

should be translated to:

```
/tutorials/dogs/search/?f=terrier
```

**Is that possible to configure Apache or Tomcat to achieve this goal? How?**
I am not sure apache is needed for this or not. This is a java application, so apache should not serve any content, just may be used to translate the path to domain, and I don't want to use different ports, since this would be one application.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html), and [mod_substitute](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html):

```
----------------------
#required modules
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
----------------------

<Location "/">
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
</Location>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName examples.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass           / http://localhost:8080/TestWebApp/examples/
    ProxyPassReverse    / http://localhost:8080/TestWebApp/examples/
    Substitute          "s|/TestWebApp/examples||in"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dogs.tutorials.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass           / http://localhost:8080/TestWebApp/tutorials/dogs/
    ProxyPassReverse    / http://localhost:8080/TestWebApp/tutorials/dogs/
    Substitute          "s|/TestWebApp/tutorials/dogs||in"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cats.tutorials.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass           / http://localhost:8080/TestWebApp/tutorials/cats/
    ProxyPassReverse    / http://localhost:8080/TestWebApp/tutorials/cats/
    Substitute          "s|/TestWebApp/tutorials/cats||in"
</VirtualHost>
```

Substitute is only needed if there are non-relative links also in the response pages, so it replaces them (take care, as replacing every matching strings).

Answer (score 0):

That would require live rewriting of responses from the server too, because any url created by your webapp would say `/tutorials/dogs/search/?f=terrier`, and would have to be rewritten by the Apache frontend to `dogs.tutorials.com/search/?f=terrier`.

**Update:** A combination of [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [mod_substitution](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_substitute.html) should be able to do it.

I would not recommend this for performance and complexity reasons.

However, if the 3 URLs are actually 3 different webapps, then you can do it with [virtual hosting](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html), where the 3 webapps are `ROOT` apps for 3 different virtual hosts.

Comment: Yes, of course the responses also. Not different applications, I ask how to handle for one application at different paths.

Comment: I am aware about performance and complexity issues, these will be only simple online tools probably on different domains or subdomains serving by one application base.

Comment: For example this is online: http://log4jtester.com/ , and I want to extend the project with more tools on separated domains. The code would be remain clean, it's simpler having one app than separating, and the traffic is very low.

Comment: Actually, I think that separating the code for different domains into separate webapps, is a far more "clean" way of doing it. You can then also restart and update them independently. And you may well need to host them on different Tomcat instances in the future, because they become so popular that you need to scale out.

Comment: I understand your point, of course the code would built from different modules, just assembled to single app as also having some common codebases. I found this the simplest way now, and when it necessary to make separated app, it remains quite simple to do. On the other hand the question targeted this scenario even it is reasonable or not, that could be helpful for others.

Comment: If you compare assembling 3 webapps and using virtual hosting to assembling 1 webapp and implement rewrite+substitute on top of that, I know what I would consider the *simplest way*: 3 webapps. It's also a lot less error-prone.

Comment: I like url rewriting, and I want to learn it used for this case. Later probably I go to the other way, but still learned something, I do often this. And if I create 20 formatter, I will not prefer to deploy them separately